# How to merge two CSV files with Linux column wise?

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I am looking for a simple line of code (if possible) to simply merge two files column wise and save the final result into a new file.

Edited to response to the first answer @heitor:

By using `paste file1.csv file2.csv`, What happened is:

For instance file 1:

```
A B
1 2
```

file2:

```
C D
3 4
```

By doing `paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv >output.csv` I got

```
 A B
 C D
 1 2
 3 4
```

not

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

By doing `cat file1.csv file2.csv` I got

```
A B 
1 2
C D
3 4
```

Neither of them is what I want. Any idea?

Any idea?

Comment: I see your files are space separated, you should use `-d " "` to join them. Also, that's very weird, I've just tried the same inputs and got the expected result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `paste -d ,` to merge the two files and `>` to redirect the command output to another file:

```sh
$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv
```

E.g.:

```sh
$ cat file1.csv
A,B

$ cat file2.csv
C,D

$ paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv > output.csv

$ cat output.csv
A,B,C,D
```

`-d ,` tells paste to use `,` as the delimiter to join the columns.

`>` tells the shell to write the output of the paste command to the file `output.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed using `paste` is pretty simple,

```
$ cat file1.csv 
A B
1 2

$ cat file2.csv 
C D
3 4

$ paste -d " " file1.csv file2.csv 
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

With the `-d` option I replaced the default tab character with a space.

Edit:

In case you want to redirect that to another file then,

```
paste -d " " file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
$ cat file3.csv 
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I opened the file with a csv-viewer online and it works as expected, take a look https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-viewer-editor.htm